# DB and Web Server names changing and updating config file

Tags: sql-server

I am looking for a generic solution for the below problem
**Scenario:**
1) There are DB server and Web Servers , which are referenced in config files as DB Connection string and web service references
  eg: ***Data Source=server01;Initial Catalog=sAWSo;***

**PROBLEM:**
 So when the DB is moved from this server to another server server01, i have to go and search for all the references to this DB and update them.

Solution looking for:
I want to propose a solution to my organization such that, When the server names get changed, instead of updating the references in config they can change the ip address in one location and there will be no impact to code or config files.

Things in my mind:
A cluster server set up where one server reference will be there and many servers installed behind this server. But in my scenario not always i will have multiple servers, sometimes i might have one server itself.
My org uses something called WIP load balancer, but it is setup only for servers which has more than one server set up in load balancing.

Can we update DNS server ips, so that the reference will continue to hold the same.

I dunno if there is any support in network infrastructure for this ? Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What we do in our environment is use internal DNS for just this reason.  Each application gets its own `AppName_DB.domain.net` DNS entry that returns the IP address for `AppName`'s database server.  Whenever the database server needs to change, we just update that DNS entry.